# How to make text over background stay within it's boundaries while being responsive

Tags: html, css, css-position

How can I make my title/Nav-bar stay within the background image boundaries? When I resize my window vertically, the text goes off screen. I essentially put a fixed background image in my header section and used relative and absolute positioning to place my text items on top of the background and in the center.  This works on a static page but when I resize my window vertically, the text goes off the screen. This is what I have so far. Is there any workaround for this?

When I tried this on my footer, the text just resizes and stays within the background, no matter how small I make my window. In that part of the code I used the same exact background properties in CSS and only added additional top and bottom margins to space out my elements vertically. Everything stays within the fixed background image. What am I missing? Thank you in advance.

```css
header{
    background-color: gray;
    position: relative;
    padding: 200px 0;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(34, 44, 60, 0.7), rgba(34, 44, 60, 0.7)), url(images/header-image.jpg);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;   
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.header-wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    top:25%;
    left: 50%; 
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    color: var(--white);
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.title{
    margin: 3em 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-wrapper">
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <div class="brand">
      <h1>Tribute Page</h1>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#introduction">Introduction</a></li>
          <li><a href="#timeline">Timeline</a></li>
          <li><a href="#conclusion">Conclusion</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    <h2>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="discover-btn">
    <a href="#main">
      <ion-icon name="arrow-down-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi nicyuvi, nice to see you at SO! First off: I don't see any `font-size` settings for the `header` in your CSS. And: if it works on the footer then what's the difference in 'font-size' between `header` and `footer` (apart from not being shown here...)

Comment: Hi Rene, I have my fonts for my h1-h6 tags set to either 3rem or 2 rem. All the fonts throughout the header and footer are the same size. I tried my best to just include a snippet of my code so I'm sorry if it's harder to come up with a solution!

Comment: I need to see the CSS for the footer, **because** if the header font-settings are the same as the footer settings then the header font would resize responsively too (like you said the footer does).

Comment: `h1{
    font-size: 3rem;
}

h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6{
    font-size: 2rem;    
}

h3,
h4,
h5,
h6{
    font-weight: 700;
}` Here are the font sizes for the header and footer.

Comment: And here is the css for the footer: `footer{
    background-color: gray;
    position: relative;
    padding: 200px 0;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(34, 44, 60, 0.7), rgba(34, 44, 60, 0.7)), url(images/footer-image.jpg);
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.footer-text-wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5%;
    left: 50%; 
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    color: var(--white);
    width: 90%;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For as far as I can tell (from the snippet) you did not modify the CSS default box-model (which is `box-sizing: content-box`, [MDN: the box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model) and [w3schools: CSS box-sizing Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp). It is important to understand the CSS boxmodel, make sure to own the subject!).

The result is that:

- `header` is actually `100vh + 2 * 200px` high (`height: 100vh` plus top/bottom `padding: 200px 0`).
- you needed to use `top: 25%`  instead of (the commonly used) `50%` to center `header-wrapper` in view with `top,left,transform`. (If you did not mean to center the box, use the original 25% instead).

To solve your problem you need to use either `box-sizing: border-box` (preferred!) or correct each height or width value for all elements that use `padding,border` settings. Especially when other elements are affected by those sizes.

I used the generally accepted `box-sizing: border-box` for all elements.

Essentially the `header { padding }` got in the way!

You will need to take care of responsive sizing of the box, as the content will still move  off-screen when the viewport becomes too small...

**update** a quick and dirty solution to make your box(content) resize responsively is to set `header { font-size: 1.423vmin }`, making its size dependend on the minimum viewport size value. Also make the `h1-h6` use `em` instead of `rem` (parent fontsize dependend instead of root/html fontsize dependend).

**snippet** with corrected code:

```css
/**************************/
/* preferred global rules */
/**************************/
html,body               { box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; max-width: 100% }
*::before,*::after, *   { box-sizing: inherit }
body { margin: 0 }

/* your code with corrections */
h1                 { font-size: 3em  } /* em instead of rem */
h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { font-size: 2em  }
h3, h4, h5, h6     { font-weight: 700 }

header {
    position: relative;
    width : 100%;
    height: 100vh;   

    font-size: 1.423vmin; /* ADD for responsiveness */

/*    padding: 200px 0; /* REMOVE, useless in the 'header/.header-wrapper' construction */

    background-color: gray;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(34, 44, 60, 0.7), rgba(34, 44, 60, 0.7)), url(https://via.placeholder.com/500);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.header-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top : 50%; /* MOD from 25% */
    left: 50%;

    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.title {
    margin: 3em 0;
    color: CornSilk; /* ADD for testing */
}

footer {
    position: relative;
    padding: 200px 0;
    width: 100%;

    background-color: gray;
/*    background: linear-gradient(rgba(34, 44, 60, 0.7), rgba(34, 44, 60, 0.7)), url(images/footer-image.jpg);/**/
    background-color: CornFlowerBlue;

    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat
}
.footer-text-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    color: var(--white);
    width: 90%
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="header-wrapper">
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <div class="brand">
                <h1>Tribute Page</h1>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#introduction">Introduction</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#timeline">Timeline</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#conclusion">Conclusion</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>

        <div class="title">
            <h2>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="discover-btn">
            <a href="#main">
                <ion-icon name="arrow-down-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<footer>
    <div class="footer-wrapper">
        some footer
    </div>
</footer>
```